# Searching and Sorting Using MySQL Inner Join

Tags: mysql, inner-join, sql-like

I guess I can't explain my problem properly. I want to explain this to you with a picture.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNpMO.jpg)
In the first picture you can see the hashtags in the trend section. These hashtags are searched for the highest total and it is checked whether the date has passed. If valid data is available, the first 5 hashtags are taken.

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqmX8.jpg)
In the second picture, it is checked whether the posts in the hashtag are in the post, if any, the oldest date value is taken, LIMIT is set to 1 and the id value from the oyuncular table is matched with sid. Thus, the name of the person sharing can be accessed.

[Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vmv5.jpg)

My English is a little bad, I hope I could explain it properly.

```
SELECT
    social_trend.hashtag,
    social_trend.total,
    social_trend.tarih,
    social_post.sid,
    social_post.tarih,
    social_post.post,
    oyuncular.id,
    oyuncular.isim
FROM
    social_trend
INNER JOIN
    social_post
ON
    social_post.post LIKE '%social_trend.hashtag%' ORDER BY social_post.tarih LIMIT 1
INNER JOIN
    oyuncular
ON
    oyuncular.id = social_post.sid
WHERE
    social_trend.tarih > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ORDER BY social_trend.total DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: You should specify your question. We can not know, what does your error is, if you won't share any exception or something special depending on your code.

Answer (score 0):

YOu should use a sibquery
and add a proper join between subqiery and social_trend
(i assumed  sing both sid)

```
 SELECT
    social_trend.hashtag,
    social_trend.total,
    social_trend.tarih,
    t.sid,
    t.tarih,
    t.post,
    oyuncular.id,
    oyuncular.isim
FROM     (
select social_post.* 
from social_post
INNER JOIN social_trend  ON  social_post.post LIKE concat('%',social_trend.hashtag,'%' )
ORDER BY social_post.tarih LIMIT 1
) t 
INNER JOIN social_trend ON social_trend.hashtag= t.post
INNER JOIN  oyuncular ON  oyuncular.id = t.sid
WHERE
    social_trend.tarih > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ORDER BY social_trend.total DESC LIMIT 5
```

but looking to your new explanation and img  seems you need

```
 SELECT
    t.hashtag,
    t.total,
    t.tarih_trend,
    t.sid,
    t.tarih,
    t.post,
    oyuncular.id,
    oyuncular.isim
FROM     (
    select social_post.sid
        , social_post.tarih
        , social_post.post
        , st.hashtag
        , st.total
        , st.tarih tarih_trend
    from social_post
    INNER JOIN (
        select * from social_trend
        WHERE social_trend.tarih > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
        order by total DESC LIMIT 5
    ) st ON  social_post.post LIKE concat('%',st.hashtag,'%' )
    ORDER BY social_post.tarih LIMIT 5
) t 
INNER JOIN  oyuncular ON  oyuncular.id = t.sid
```

Comment: social_trend.sid doesn't really matter. The important thing is that social_trend.hashtag matches social_post.post, and I want it to pull the data if players.id and social_post.sid match with this match.

Comment: answer  updated for match social_trend.hashtag= social_post.post

Comment: When I run the query I can't get any data. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expcted  result

Comment: answer updated with a subquery for like on hatsag

Comment: I tried your query and this time I get an error such as Duplicate column name 'id'.

Comment: answer updated ..  with fully qualified request

Comment: Your query worked fine, but I still couldn't get any data. I explained my problem in detail on the subject. Can you look again?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but this time I get error #1054 - Unknown column 'st.tarih_trend' in 'field list'

Comment: answer  updated  with correct column alias

Comment: Your query worked fine, but only one of them is coming, while 5 hashtag data should come. How can i fix this.

Comment: The trending hashtag should only pull 1 of the shared posts. Your code is pulling 5 posts this time. I want 5 different hashtags and 1 of the oldest posts shared. I'm sorry I disturbed you a lot, too.

Comment: I tried to change it but I am getting an error because I am a bit new to sql queries.